# Materials, shaders and outlining the object in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

How can I outline an ingame object? (for a purpose of showing the player selection). Lets say I have 5 goblins and I want to outline only the one that intersects with cursor.

My knowledge of materials and shader is very weak so maybe I dont understand correctly, but...

...most answers I have seen are using something like outline shader.

But that would mean I would have to do two versions of material for each selectable object? Since just changing the shader would change every other object with the same material?

Isnt there some better way?

Comment: If you're looking for a quick solution, there are (paid) assets on the Asset Store that do such a thing: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41508. (Not really my recommendation if this is for hobbyist/educational purposes, since in that case it's a lot better if you first tried to code a solution for yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you my code. I used this code to highlight objects in a room that are selected and used Raycasting. You can highlight only one object, if select another, the old will be deselected... Ignore the comments, they are in german :D

[HighlightCode](http://pastebin.com/gpX3MEau)

[Highlight Children](http://pastebin.com/NiVxHxBT)

If you want to use a outline-shader, here is a good one: [Outlined Diffuse](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse)

Comment: I have several questions: 1) Is there a variant of this shader that works with the new unity 5 standard shader? 2) What if the object I want to highlight is composed of few smaller objects? (like body + weapon) Wont it mess the outline? 3) What color are you changing when highlighting? Is it albedo color?

Comment: Lets talk about my highlightCode, because I just onces used Shaders and I am a noob in this topic.
I updated my code and the link I used in my answer.

**2)** I used my highlightCode to highlight an object that has a lot of other objects as childs. You just need to enter the children and change there material too.

**3)** It takes the current color of your object and just add a value:
`new Color(oldColor.r + highlightFactor, oldColor.g + highlightFactor, oldColor.b + highlightFactor, oldColor.a);`

**1)** I guess there are a lot of tutorials how to use shaders

Comment: I am also very new to the shaders and materials, so I dont understand one thing? The color you are changing - that is base material color (albedo)? Many models I use are from asset store and they have base material color of white, so I guess I would have to darken them a bit.

Comment: Yes and no, if the color of your object is white then it will be brighter, maybe unfavorable^^ . But if the object is red, it will be a bright red. You can try an take a negative value so it would be darker and not brigther

Comment: If the color is white, how it can be brighter after adding highlightFactor? I thought maximum is 255/255/255 which is white.

Comment: In this case I don't know, just try. I never used it on white objects.

Comment: It actually works with textured objects with white albedo. Just tried it. Dont know why, but it works, so thanks :) Btw it might be better to use oldColor * highlight instead of oldColor+highlight since it better preserves the RGB ratio of original color.